# Calling a formatting method

Tags: java

I am very confused on how to calling a format method so that a String is printed with an `int` within it.

```
//call
boatPrice = inputBoatPrice("Please enter the price of the boat, must be > :", 0.0);

//method
public static double inputBoatPrice(String messagePassed, double limitPassed) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    do {
        System.out.printf("%1s %1.2f\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    }  while(userInput < limitPassed);
    return userInput;
} //end method
```

How can I fix this so that the call prints out:

> "Please enter the price of the boat, must be > 0.0:"

Currently it prints out

> "Please enter the price of the boat, must be > : 0.00"

Answer (score 1):

just adapt your printf to:

```
System.out.printf("%1s %1.1f\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format string contains %1.2f, which means print a minimum of one digit total and 2 digits after the period. Changing it to %1.1f will mean print a minimum of 1 digit total and 1 digit after the period.

You will find this in the Javadoc under Formatter. The first number is the width and the second number is the precision. From the Javadoc:

## Width

The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. For the line separator conversion, width is not applicable; if it is provided, an exception will be thrown.

## Precision

For general argument types, the precision is the maximum number of characters to be written to the output.

**For the floating-point conversions 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the number of digits after the decimal separator**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT ::
I think all you want to do is print in a specific format of 1.1 with that colon at the end. Then you need this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputBoatPrice("Please enter the price of the boat, must be >",0.0);
    }

    public static double inputBoatPrice(String messagePassed, double limitPassed) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
        do {
            System.out.printf("%1s %1.1f :\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);
            userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        }  while(userInput < limitPassed);
        return userInput;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is why the printf call is displaying 2 decimal points when the desired format is one,

Comment: well yeah I can see the change in question details as well. edited the answer as well @MichaelMurray

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this I adjust your `printf` and right typr of return:

```
  public static double inputBoatPrice(String messagePassed, double limitPassed)
  {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double userInput;
  do {
        System.out.printf("%1s %1.1f\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);

        userInput = keyboard.nextDouble();

     } while(userInput < limitPassed);

       return userInput;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
System.out.printf("%1s %1.2f\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);
```

to

```
System.out.printf(messagePassed, limitPassed);
```

and your String to

```
"Please enter the price of the boat, must be > %1.1f :"
```

This helps to correct the problem with your string.

You also have to adjust your `userInput` variable, as you want to read oubles (at least you ask for double values and therefore you should accept only double values). This means changing the type of `userInput` as well as `keyboard.nextInt();` to `keyboard.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to your code:

```
double boatPrice = inputBoatPrice("Please enter the price of the boat, must be > ", 0.0);

public static double inputBoatPrice(String messagePassed, double limitPassed) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    do {
         System.out.print(messagePassed + limitPassed + ":");
         userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    }  while(userInput < limitPassed);

    return userInput;
}
```

You need to change your System.out.print from:

```
System.out.printf("%1s %1.2f\n", messagePassed, limitPassed);
```

to:

```
System.out.print(messagePassed + limitPassed + ":");
```

Also edit the string that you pass when you call the method inputBoatPrice:

```
("...must be > :") to ("...must be > ")
```